# Hide part of div which is under a transparent div

Tags: html, css

I have 2 div's and the upper div is transparent with a border radius on every corner, there is a div which is using solid background gradient underneath this and has been pushed up under the transparent div using a negative margin and z-index to put it behind the upper div.

Is there a way with CSS to hide the part of the div which is up underneath the div above it?

I did it this way because I need to maintain the corners which are highlighted in the second image.

[image: Problem example]
[image: Problem corners]

Problem using color stops illustrated here:

jsfiddle.net/PKy8B/3/

As someone asked this would be the desired result:

[image: Desired Result]

Thanks everyone for the help but it looks like this is not possible to do this with a transparent div above and one behind, I have changed the top div to no longer be transparent just as a "best fix" option.

Comment: Post your code and make a http://www.jsfiddle.net. Thanks

Comment: do you want to remove the rounded corner as you circled in red?

Comment: No. The div is transaprent and there's not much you can do about it. What you **could** do is not start the background-gradient until **after** the div has cleared the 'overhang' using a color-stop.

Comment: No I want to hide the part which is behind the top div at the bottom you can see the line where its been pushed up with negative margin. If I use colour stop there will be a blank bit where the red cicles are do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the div is transparent and there's not much you can do about it. What you could do is not start the background-gradient until after the div has cleared the 'overhang' using a color-stop.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PKy8B/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.top {
    height:75px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.bottom {
    height:75px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, 
        rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,
        rgba(0,0,0,0) 10px, /* end transparent section*/
        rgba(255,0 ,0 ,0.25) 10px, /* start visible section */
        rgba(255,0,0,.25) 100%);
    border:1px solid black; /* added for visual reference */
    z-index:-1
}
```

**NOTE**: The color stop **must** be the same as the amount you have moved the bottom div

Comment: As I said: 
"I did it this way because I need to maintain the corners which are highlighted in the second image."

Comment: Then I guess we'll/you'll have to re-think.

Comment: Then perhaps you could provide a fiddle of your current HTML & CSS so we can see what we can adapt.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do the same to the top just like you do to top-

I mean -

if you have added `linear-gradient(to bottom` in `bottom` div

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, 
        rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,
        rgba(0,0,0,0) 10px, /* end transparent section*/
        rgba(255,0 ,0 ,0.25) 10px, /* start visible section */
        rgba(255,0,0,.25) 100%);
```

then you can also also do the same for Top:

i mean do something like that with `top`

add this - `linear-gradient(to top`

```
background: linear-gradient(to top, 
        rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,
        rgba(0,0,0,0) 10px, /* end transparent section*/
        rgba(0,0 ,0 ,0.25) 10px, /* start visible section */
        rgba(0,0,0,.25) 100%);
```

CHECK it here - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shailparas/PKy8B/4/)

And i think your `See More` blue button will be an image. so there will be no issue with it.

Comment: @Sam - what should be your desire result? can post any snap for that?

Comment: See original post bottom image.